# Test class not running properly from loop in TestSuite... in seleniumRC+JUNIT

Tags: java, junit, selenium-rc

I am using SeleniumRC+Java+JUnit+Eclipse.

I have a test class as ABC and I'm running this test class from a TestSuite. I am following certain conditions to run the test class like this:

- In an excel sheet I have 3 columns as colA, ColB, ColC and rows as Run, Username, Password.
  colA, ColB, ColC have values in the Run row as Yes, No, Yes respectively.
- My Condition is: only when a column has value the "Yes" in the Run row, the test class will execute taking corresponding username and password from that column.

But my problem is, everytime the loop is running till last "Yes" valued column and executing the test class for corresponding username and password, ignoring previous "Yes" valued columns. **Why is this the case?**

Code for TestSuite:

```
public class FinalTestSuite extends TestCase 
{
    public static File sourceFile = new File("C:/Selenium/selenium-remote-control-1.0.3/Data.xls");
    public static WorkbookSettings ws;
    public static WritableWorkbook workbook;
    public static WritableSheet wSheet1, wSheet2;
    public static Sheet sh1, sh2, sheetFinal;
    public static Workbook sourceWorkbook;
    public static Label label;
    public Selenium selenium;
    public static int colCount, rowCount;
    public static int colNum;
    public static int rowNum;

    public static TestSuite suite() throws Exception
    {  
        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();  
        sourceWorkbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(sourceFile);
        sheetFinal = sourceWorkbook.getSheet("Begin");
        colCount = sheetFinal.getColumns();
        System.out.println(colCount);
        rowCount = sheetFinal.getRows();
        System.out.println(rowCount);

        for(int col=1;col<colCount;col++)
        {
            if((sheetFinal.getCell(col,1).getContents()).equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
            {
                for(rowNum = 1;rowNum<=rowCount;rowNum++)
                {
                    if((sheetFinal.getCell(0, rowNum-1).getContents()).equalsIgnoreCase("username"))
                    {
                        id = sheetFinal.getCell(col, rowNum-1).getContents();
                    }
                    else if((sheetFinal.getCell(0, rowNum-1).getContents()).equalsIgnoreCase("Password"))
                    {
                        pwd = sheetFinal.getCell(col, rowNum-1).getContents();
                    }

                }

                suite.addTestSuite(ABC.class);
            }
        }

        return suite;
    } 

    public static void main(String a) 
    {
        TestRunner.run(ABC.class);
    }

}
```

Did I go wrong anywhere?

Comment: I tried to clarify your question a bit - please check that it still says what you wanted to say.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed:

```
public static void main(String a)
{
    TestRunner.run(ABC.class);
}
```

And replaced `suite.addTestSuite(ABC.class);` with `TestRunner.run(ABC.class);`

Now it's working fine.